# Is Netduino awaiting a second run?

Tags: netduino

I didn't jump on Netduino when I should have now it looks like they are in a very limited supply. Does any one know if there is going to be any more manufactured or possibly the beta Netduino?

Comment: Are you referring to the original Netduino or the recently-announced Netduino Plus?

Answer (score 2):

[Little Bird](http://www.littlebirdelectronics.com/products/netduino.html) are still taking orders for the [original](http://www.littlebirdelectronics.com/products/netduino.html). Might a while for the new one (November?)

Answer (score 1):

New stock is arriving at dealers in the next few days.
October 1st is the slated delivery date for US dealers, not sure about AU.

I still have [one left](http://stores.ebay.com.au/Microcontrollers-and-More) in stock in AU

Answer (score 1):

There are others available in UK

http://www.coolcomponents.co.uk/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=559